# Information about multiple graphs in list (igraph)

Tags: r, function, loops, igraph

Good evening,
I have a medium-sized number of graphs (42) that I need information about (e.g. transitivity scores). All graphs are iGraph objects. My goal is to write the info from my function directly into a dataframe. However, the composition of my graphs change: some nodes stay the same, but some other nodes are different for each wave.

My current approach looks like this:

```
#example graphs:
g1 <- graph.star(n=10, mode="out")
g2 <- graph.star(n=14, mode="out")
g3 <- graph.star(n=12, mode="out")
g4 <- graph.star(n=17, mode="in")

# make a list of graphs:
g_list <- (g1,g2,g3,g4)

# here is the function I wrote:
calc.transitivity <- function(g_list){
g_trans <- (transitivity(g_list))
return(g_trans)
}

# let it run:
info.trans <- lapply(g_list, calc.transitivity)
```

Works fair enough for me. Now, ideally I could add more things in there (e.g. centralization.betweenness) and also functions that calculate things on the nodal level (e.g. which node has the highest degree in a year?). I want to write this into a data-frame but am unsure how to a) respect the changes in node compositions per graph and b) don't know if I can get info about single nodes in there and have the graphs as some sort of "aggregated unit".

Thanks for the help in advance. I am also interested if there is a more elegant way to write my function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - not elegant, but it works:

```
calc.density <- function(g_list){
g_dens <- (edge_density(g_list))
return(g_dens)
}

list_density <- lapply(g_sb, calc.density)
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 1, nrow = 323))
d$density <- unlist(list_density)
```